# Mapping Backbone Models to serialized array in wp_options table

Tags: ajax, backbone

I want to create a to do list to use Backbone in the context of WordPress, and i want to save models as single serialized array via update_option(), the problem is that i don't know how to mappe the models to this array so i can use model.fetch(id) and model.destroy(id).

```
 MyTodo.TodoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        'title': 'testtitre',
        'done': false,
        'priority':'2'
    },

    idAttribute: 'todoId',

    url: ajaxurl,


    toggle: function(){
        this.set({'done': !this.get('done')});
    },

    // Adapt save() to work with wordpress ajax
    save: function(){
        var $params = {
        emulateJSON: true,
        data: {
             action: 'test',
             payload : this.toJSON()
          }
        };
        return Backbone.sync( 'create', this, $params );
    },



});
```